# Regex: word boundaries

Tags: regex, word-boundary

I have to search words containing capitalized letters or numbers.

I use `\b[^ ]*[A-Z0-9]+[^ ]*\b`, however instead of `[^ ]` i would like to use `[^\b]`, but this selects all the phrase...

**`This`**`is`**`Some`**`text, that has`**`s0me`****`nUm8ers`**`, like`**`Boeing-380`**`or`**`RNA-78`**`.`**`That`**`is`**`GREAT!`**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use `\w*` for matching zero or more word characters.

```
\w*[A-Z0-9-]+\w*
```

or

```
\S*[A-Z0-9]+\S*
```

And note that you can't include `\b`, `\B` inside a character class. You could achieve the result without including the both inside a character class through some other ways. `\S*` matches zero or more non-space characters.

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/vK9wN4/1)

Comment: added an alternative. pls provide an example.

Comment: What's your expected output?

Comment: the output will be the words in bold

Comment: comas etc... seems like `\w*[A-Z-0-9]+\w*` works well! please add it to answer ;)

Comment: forget the "-" in A-Z-0-9 ;)

Comment: @Serge then the above would match `-` alone in `FOO - BAR` . is this ok?

Comment: as in the OP, `boeing-380` will match, but `FOO - BAR` will not, cause of spaces...